# ¿Cómo hacer el Test de Punteado de Lahy con Arduino?

Tags: arduino, hardware

Quiero implementar el test de punteado de Lahy con Arduino, algo como esto:

[image: Test de Lahy]

**Donde necesito que el arduino:**

1. Detecte cuando el punto toca "metal de acierto" (agujeros)
2. Detecte cuando el puntero toca "metal de error"(disco giratorio y disco inferior)

Lo que hice hasta ahora fue conectar el metal (los agujeros por ejemplo) con con una pin de salida (`OUTPUT`) en `HIGH` y el puntero a un pin de entrada (`INPUT`) para detectar el contacto, pero no me funciona al imprimir en el puerto serial, es impreciso y arroja valores que parecen aleatorios, coloqué diferentes valores de Delay al bucle de la función `loop` pero esto no solucionó el problema.

**Circuito:**

[image: Circuito]

**Código (intentando desactivar la detección hasta levantar el contacto)**

```cpp
int discHitPin = 7;
int pointer = 8;
bool pointerActive = true;

void setup() {
  pinMode(discHitPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(pointer, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pointer, HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

    int discHitPinSignal = digitalRead(discHitPin);
    if(discHitPinSignal == HIGH){
      if(pointerActive){
        Serial.println("HIT");
        pointerActive = false;
        Serial.println("Puntero desactivado");
      }        
    } else {
      if(!pointerActive) {
        pointerActive = true;
        Serial.println("Puntero activado");
      }
    }
}
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea o pista de cómo hacer esto?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si publicas el código y el circuito, te podriamos ayudar.

Comment: En el fondo es un Arduino con dos botones. Uno que refleja éxito (la persona tocó el circulo pequeño) y otro fracaso (el disco rotante toco el lápiz).

Comment: @CandidMoe edite la pregunta para colocar lo que dices. Gracias por el interés.

Answer (score 1):

El problema planteado se reduce a leer el estado de dos botones (interruptores) que conectan a tierra cuando son pulsados. Un botón representa el disco "acierto"; el otro, el disco "error".

En tu caso no tienes físicamente un botón, pero tienes un lápiz que cierra un circuito, que es lo mismo.

Cuando se habla de botones el principal problema es el `debouncing`: al presionar un botón (o conectar dos cables, pinchar un disco con un lápiz) se produce una serie caótica de contactos durante unos milisegundos, lo que hace que tus `digitalRead` te retornen una serie caótica de HIGH y LOW.

Arduino tiene varias librerías para manejar botones, como [Bounce2](https://github.com/thomasfredericks/Bounce2). Estudialas.

**El circuito correcto**

Tienes que detectar dos eventos: tocar "acierto" y tocar "error". Significa que tienes que tener dos pines en INPUT. Más precisamente, tienes que configurarlo con INPUT_PULLUP, de manera que los pines queden conectados a Vcc y `digitalRead` te retorne HIGH cuando el lápiz no está tocando el pin.

Si sólo los configuras de INPUT, los pines quedan flotando, sin un voltaje definido, y pueden retornar cualquier cosa mientras no los conectes a Vcc o GND.

El "lápiz" lo conectas a GND. Cuando el lápiz toca "acierto", el pin conecta a GND y `digitalRead` te retorna LOW. Lo mismo, cuando toca "error".

Para estos fines, suponemos que disco giratorio y disco inferior están eléctricamente conectados, por lo que no necesitamos distinguirlos en el código.

**Debouncing**

Vamos a hacer un debouncing supersimple: cuando el `digitalRead` retorna LOW (el lápiz toca el disco), nos quedaremos leyendo el mismo pin a intervalos de 150ms hasta que retorne a HIGH. No es perfecto, pero debería servir para el uso propuesto, puesto que en esta aplicación los toques son rápidos y breves. Luego puedes usar una librería para mejorar el debouncing, de ser necesario.

**Código**

```
#define ACIERTO 6
#define ERROR 7

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  pinMode(ACIERTO, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(ERROR, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(ACIERTO) == LOW) {
    Serial.println("Acierto");
    do {
      delay(150);
    }
    while (digitalRead(ACIERTO) == LOW);
  } else {
    if (digitalRead(ERROR) == LOW) {
      Serial.println("Error");
      do {
        delay(150);
      }
      while (digitalRead(ERROR) == LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo**

- El cable blanco está conectado a GND y representa el lápiz.
- El cable rojo está conectado al pin 7 y representa el disco de error.
- El cable amarillo está conectado al pin 6 y representa el disco de acierto.

[image: Circuito de prueba]

Comment: wow! Muchas gracias, seguire los consejos y comento como me va. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @JosephLeon. Hice una edición para mejorar el debouncing. Revisa el código.

Comment: Muchas gracias, probé y todo perfecto!